# DRF The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form - ImageField

Tags: django, json, djangorestframework, serialización

Tengo el siguiente modelo User:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
#... other attributes  
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', blank=True)
```

La serialización básica que he realizado de este modelo es:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    team = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
      queryset = queryset.select_related('team',)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username','password','first_name','last_name',
        'photo','team','position','last_login',)
```

El campo `team` es una llave foránea en el modelo User, la cual es serializada para optimizar su rendimiento en consultas a la base de datos cuando hay relaciones, con el método `setup_eager_loading function`.

La función de viewset del modelo `User` es:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import filters

from .models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer

# Viewsets define the behavior of the view
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_fields = ('username','is_player', 'first_name','last_name','team','email',)
```

Cuando voy a una instancia de un usuario en mi api serializada via Django Rest Framework, y quiero actualizar algun dato (cualquiera) de esa instancia a través de datos json puros (json raw data media type: application/json) obtengo este mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo manipular a nivel de CRUD los objetos `User` serializados en mi api a través de datos json puros en Django Rest Framework sin que tenga errores de codificación?

Answer (score 1):

Eso pasa porque esta esperando que le envies un archivo para el campo photo, si vas a hacer una edición desde el API browsable, esta envía un POST y esto se resuelve "reemplazando" todos los valores del modelo por los que estas enviando y como envias application/json en lugar de multipart arroja el error de no pudo decodificar ese campo de archivo.

Si hicieras la petición con AJAX, cURL, etc.. podrías enviar un PATCH y de esta manera actualizar parcialmente y funcionaria sin problema.

Te recomiendo que uses [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) para hacer las peticiones ya que el API Browsable de DRF se queda corta.

Saludos. Espero haberte ayudado.

*EDITO:*

Como realizar la peticion usando jQuery AJAX:

```
var username = 'mauricio';
$.ajax({
   url: '/api/users/'+username+'/',
   method: 'PATCH', 
   data : {
      first_name: 'Mauricio Alberto'
   },
   success: function(response){
     console.log(response);
   },
   error: function(response){
     console.warn(response);
   }
});
```

En este ejemplo se actualiza parcialmente usando PATCH, es decir, solo se modifica el campo `first_name`.

Comment: Genial lo que dices de Postman, lo miraré en detalle también. Pero abusando un poco, ¿tienes alguna guía sobre como puedo buscar para hacer esa petición con AJAX o actualizarlo parcialmente via application/json?

Comment: Actualizé la respuesta.